# How can I store a human animation as keyframes/baked?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, baking

I need to upload a project to render it on [Sheepit](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com), which doesn't allow scripted drivers. I used rigify and makehuman for the people, which means they have scripted drivers, so it didn't work; the person just remains in the rest pose. Is there a way to bake the animation on the deformed mesh so it's stored there?